# uwsgi + django via Nginx - uwsgi settings/spawn?

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

I am leaning towards uwsgi+nginx for my Django app, can anyone share the best method for starting up my uwsgi processes? Does anyone have experience tuning uwsgi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launchd on OSX

Upstart/init on the unices.

uwsgi also has its own process manager, so you can just run that as well.

Tuning:

Check the [mailing list](http://lists.unbit.it/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/uwsgi), for advice on your particular requirements.  Uwsgi is amazing, it is a complete deploy solution.

Nginx above 0.8.40 will build the uwsgi bindings by default, Build nginx, build uwsgi and you are golden.

Answer (score 2):

these are the functions i use in my fabfile.py file (check out python fabric if you haven't already):

```
def start_uwsgi():
    with cd(env.server.uwsgi):
        if(exists('server.pid')):
            stop_uwsgi()
            run('sleep 1')
        run('source venv/bin/activate;uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini;'))

def stop_uwsgi():
    with cd(env.server.uwsgi):
        if(exists('server.pid')):
            run('source venv/bin/activate;uwsgi --stop server.pid;'))
```

In my uwsgi.ini file i specify:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = :{{your_port}}
master = true
vhost = true
no-site = true
processes = 1
enable-threads = true
pidfile = server.pid
daemonize = server.log
auto-procname = true
procname-prefix = servername_
```

for me the main gotyas were:

- use the daemonise option if you want to keep the uwsgi server going after you close your terminal/ssh session
- use vhost to run multiple sites under the same uwsgi instance, which is great if your bottleneck is memory, like mine is with the otherwise fantastic webfaction host
- pidfile tracks the current instance, enabling you to call uwsgi --stop pidfile, uwsgi --start pidfile
- procname and procname-prefix/append give a nice name to your process so you can easily single it out using ps -u username | grep some_string

Comment: helped me a lot! +1 for the "procname"

Answer (score 0):

I will go with supervisord for managing the starting, stoping process.